# Cssmin - порядок стилей в исходнике и сжатом файле

Tags: css, сборка, frontend

Возникла задача сжать css. Использую cssmin + Grunt. Собственно вопрос. В исходнике есть такой кусок:

```css
.b-menu{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
...

.b-menu_left{
    position:absolute;
    left:-100%;
    top:-9999px;
    background-color:#4c4c4c;
    padding-left:50px;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

На выходе получаю другой порядок - сначала стили .b-menu_left, и только потом .b-menu.
Как-то можно контролировать процесс сжатия?

P.S. Прошу вопрос качества кода не рассматривать, т.к. он достался по наследству, и рефакторинг намечен на будущее.

Answer (score 1):

Эти стили в одном файле или в разных?

Если в разных - вставь свой Gruntfile.js

Comment: Этот кусок - из одного файла. Всего собирается 28 файлов.
Пробовал такие варианты сборки, результат одинаковый
https://jsfiddle.net/odmin/o5tk04t8/